# Android SQLite query cursor moveToFirst

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm making an Android App with a sqlite db, which has a query method like this:

```
String[] projection = {COLUMN_NAME_ID};
String selection = COLUMN_NAME_TEAM + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {teamId.toString()};
String sortOrder = COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " ASC";
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    //...
}
```

as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow). The point is to implement this query:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID FROM PLAYERS WHERE TEAM_ID = ? ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

According to the [SQLiteDatabase.query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) documentation, this is a valid call to query(), and so far I've been doing it successfully with all my other queries in this App.

For some reason, in this query (and only in this) the App freezes in `c.moveToFirst()`.

Some answers to similar questions suggest that it might be a performance issue. I don't think this is the case, as my table has only 6 rows and the query is quite simple.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any difference if you use `String selection = COLUMN_NAME_TEAM + " = '?'";`?

Comment: You may consider creating an index on this column in the table. Refer to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference: instead of freezing, it crashes.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Nothing. It freezes just like the app.

Comment: @Karakuri turns out the problem is in the c.moveToFirst() rather than the query. But I still haven't found the reason.